# What is the limit function of $f_n(x) := \begin{cases} (x-n+1)(n+1-x): n-1 < x < n+1\\ 0: x \leq n-1 \lor x \geq n+1 \end{cases}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

I have a question about the convergence of $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ with
$$
f_n(x) := \begin{cases} (x-n+1)(n+1-x): n-1 < x < n+1\\ 0: x \leq n-1 \lor x \geq n+1 \end{cases}.
$$
Does this sequence of functions converge and if so what is its limit function? Does it converge point wise or also uniformly?
**What I have done so far:**
I plotted some elements of the sequence to see how it behaves (I know this is also kind of obvious already from the definition but I did it anyways)
[image: some elements of the function sequence]

and I realized that the sequence consists just of these "hills" that look like $f(x)=-x^2+1$ and shoot off to positive infinity. *What I don't get about this is how this could every possibly converge to anything* since it clearly does not "stop" sliding off to the right. But of course the functions values *always stay the same* and I am sure herein lies the "trick" somewhere.
I thought of trying to prove that
$$
f_n \to f = \begin{cases} -x^2+1: -1 < x < 1\\ 0: x \leq -1 \lor x \geq 1 \end{cases} \ (n \to \infty)
$$
but I got stuck when taking $x \in [1, \infty)$ because even if $f=0$ at that point I cannot conclude the same for any $f_n(x)$. The same problem occurs if I assume $-1 < x < 1$. What about the values of $f_n(x)$ on that interval?
Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Doesn't $f_n$ converge to $0$? Given any $x$, choose $N > x+1$. Then for all $n\geq N$, we would have $x<n-1$. Hence $f_n(x)=0, \forall \, n\geq N$. Thus $f_n(x)$ converges to $0$.

Comment: Further, the convergence is not uniform. On contrary, if it had been so, then there would have existed a common $N$ for a given $\epsilon$ satisfying $|f_n(x)| < \epsilon$ for all $x$ and for all $n\geq N$. Now, fix an $\epsilon<1$ and choose an $n$ very large (greater than $N$ corresponding to $\epsilon$). Now $n\in (n-1, n+1)$. Thus $f_n(n) = 1$ as per the definition which is greater than $\epsilon$.

Comment: @YathirajSharma Thanks for commenting! I will think about what you said and report back soon.

Comment: @YathirajSharma Okay so I am pretty sure what you commented is correct. Would you like to sum it up in an answer so people see that this question has a solution? Otherwise I will try to.

Comment: Okay.I will add the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite clear that $\{f_n\}$ converges pointwise to $0$. This is because, for any given $x\in \mathbb{R}$, choosing $N_x\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x<N_x-1$, then for all $n\geq N_x$, we would have $x < n-1$ and hence by definition $f_n(x)=0$, for all $n\geq N_x$, implying that $\{f_n(x)\}$ converges to $0$.

However, the convergence is not uniform. This is because, for each $n$, we have $n\in (n-1, n+1)$, forcing by definition that
$$f_n(n) =1.$$

Hence, for any $\epsilon <1$, it would not hold good that there exists an $N_{\epsilon}$ such that for all $n\geq N_{\epsilon}$, we would have
$$|f_n(x)| < \epsilon,$$
for all $x$.